# I can't get item's to show in my table From database

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I was making a Crud in Django but I can't see the items from the database and I can create contracts but can't see them en edit them en delete them. I use this with a javascript code for and ajax that I don't need to reload the page

this is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Django

# Django
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
# Project
from .forms import ContractForm
from .models import Contract
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PassRequestMixin, DeleteAjaxMixin


class Index(generic.ListView):
    model = Contract
    context_object_name = 'contracten'
    template_name = 'contract/index.html'


# Create
class ContractCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'contract/create_contract.html'
    form_class = ContractForm
    success_message = 'Success: contract aan gemaakt.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


# Update
class ContractUpdateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Contract
    template_name = 'contract/delete_contract.html'
    form_class = ContractForm
    success_message = 'Success: contract upgedated.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


# Read
class ContractReadView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Contract
    template_name = 'contract/read_contract.html'


# Delete
class ContractDeleteView(DeleteAjaxMixin, generic.DeleteView):
    model = Contract
    template_name = 'contract/delete_contract.html'
    success_message = 'Success: Book was deleted.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')


def contract(request):
    return render(request, 'contract/index.html'),
```

my idex.html code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  {% include "_modal.html" %}

  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            <button class="create-Contract btn btn-primary" type="button" name="button">
              <span class="fa fa-plus mr-2"></span>maak contract aan</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 mb-3">
            {% if contracten %}
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">#</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">organisatie</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">tussenpersoon</th>
                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">tussenpersoon_email</th>

                    <th class="text-center" scope="col">lezen / Updaten / verwijderen</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for contract in contracten %}
                    <tr>
                      <th class="text-center" scope="row">{{ contract.id }}</th>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ contract.organisatie }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ contract.tussenpersoon }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ contract.tussenpersoon_email }}</td>

                      <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="read-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'read_Contract' contract.id %}">
                          <span class="fa fa-eye"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="update-Contract btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-id="{% url 'update_Contract' contract.id %}">
                          <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="delete-Contract btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{% url 'delete_Contract' contract.id %}">
                          <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                        </button>

                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            {% else %}
              <p class="text-primary">u heeft nog geen contracten</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block extrascripts %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

      // Create book button
      $(".create-Contract").modalForm({formURL: "{% url 'create_Contract' %}"});

      // Update book buttons
      $(".update-Contract").each(function () {
        $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
      });

      // Read book buttons
      $(".read-Contract").each(function () {
        $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
      });

      // Delete book buttons
      $(".delete-Contract").each(function () {
        $(this).modalForm({formURL: $(this).data('id')});
      });

    });
  </script>
{% endblock extrascripts %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Contract(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    organisatie = models.CharField(max_length=145, null=False, blank=False)
    tussenpersoon = models.CharField(max_length=145, null=True, blank=True)
    tussenpersoon_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Contract
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin

class ContractForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = ('organisatie','tussenpersoon','tussenpersoon_email',)
```

I hope that someone​ can help me with my code

Comment: if you don't use the JavaScript can you see the data?

Comment: it doesn't work if I get rid of the javascript